# Get simple product from option value

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product

In a configurable product how do I get which simple product the option value belongs to? For example say if I had the following I want to know which simple product id is related to the option value 167

```
<select class="required-entry super-attribute-select" id="attribute164" name="super_attribute[164]">
    <option value="">Choose an Option...</option>
    <option value="168" price="0">1 x 400g</option>
    <option value="167" price="13.98">6 x 400g +€14.96</option>
</select>
```

Comment: do you need this via models etc or is it only on the front end?

Answer (score 0):

This post has helped me out loads http://hkpatel201.blogspot.in/2012/09/getting-selected-simple-product-id-in.html